# How to create a fixed panel that is always visible when I scroll on my splunk dashboard?

Tags: javascript, css, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I added the fieldset into a panel row, and now I want to keep this panel visible when I scroll in my dashboard like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/T2PL5/85/)

But like in the example, I want to keep the sidebar on the top when the wrapper text disappears.
i'm sure i need javascript instance to perform this
now i just use css code : `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your XML dashboard to HTML and modify the CSS of the panel you want to have absolute positioning.

Comment: my dashboards is an html,
but i don't know how can i do that

Comment: so what you're looking for is not Splunk, but CSS related. (sorry for the late reply)